# Rails 3 Specify Fallback Format if MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile-fu

I have a rails 3.2 application that recently I added mobile-fu gem to, in order to add separate mobile views.
There were a few hiccups but, for the most part, it works wonderfully.

However, I've only made mobile views for a handful of pages.  When I attempt to go to a page that does not have a mobile view, from a mobile device, I get:

```
Missing template after_hour_it_supports/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :prawn, :prawn_dsl]}
```

Which is what I would expect.

However, it is necessary to display some pages which might never have mobile counterparts.  Specifically, there is a page to approve something.  The thing that they are approving might never have a mobile view made for it, but the approval page already has a mobile view.  My current approach, is to use an iframe to display the possibly non-mobile view.  Of course, if a mobile view exists, I would prefer to use it over the non-mobile view (still in the iframe).

So what I would like to do is to attempt to render template with the :mobile format, but if the mobile format does not exist, to render with the :html format, which seems like something rails already does based on the `:formats` array mentioned in the MissingTemplate exception.  I can find some documentation on how to set the `:formats` array when calling render, but I would like to do this automatically, without having to modify every existing response.

How do I modify `:formats=>[:mobile]` to be `:formats=>[:mobile, :html]` on an application level?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863257/changing-view-formats-in-rails-3-1-delivering-mobile-html-formats-fallback-on?rq=1) which seems to work for me (the answer by Will Madden).

Specifically, I used his suggestion to override the `formats=` in my ApplicationController.  Which he says is the same way that rails already adds this exact same functionality for the :js format.

The specific method he writes in his answer looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController
    ...
    def formats=(values)
        values << :html if values == [:mobile]
        super(values)
    end
    ...
end
```

This is by far the most elegant solution I have found for my circumstances.  However, it fails whenever the controller for the page in question contains a respond_to block for the current action.