# ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template (Trying to render nonexistent :mobile format )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an `index.js` in place which is fired ok from desktop but gives the following error when I try to open from Mobile Safari.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template ads/thumbs/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:es, :en], :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.2/app/views" * "/app/app/views"
```

I'm not sure why it is looking for a `:formats=>[:mobile]` when there's no such a file in the folder.

Same thing happens after trying to sign in with devise from mobile phone. I tries to render a nonexistent `create.mobile.haml` file.

P.S. [Is there a way to make `:mobile` views to fallback default `:html` views when not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062518/can-a-mobile-mime-type-fall-back-to-html-in-rails) That would make the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should in general respond with content-type specific views. In this case, a simple way to get past this short-term issue is to rename `index.js` to `index.mobile.js`.

Rails attempts to render views that are specific to the content-type requested -- for example, `index.html.haml` when html is requested or `show.json.haml` if you request json. In this case the content-type requested is `:mobile`.

In the long run you should develop views that will be sent back when different content types are requested.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the app is asking for `:mobile` only on that page. In the rest of the app I don't have any `:mobile` version and is rendering the regular views with no problems. Is there any solution to this that doesn't involve copy again the file and rename it?

Comment: Sorry - not trying to imply you didn't understand. I didn't know how much to assume you understood. There are lots of people here with less knowledge.

Comment: Isn't this against the Rails principle of Don't repeat yourself? If I need to add a mobile version of every view I would end up with a lot of repetition for sure. I'm still looking for a more a-la Rails approach.

Comment: Not really, it's the design of rails to allow you to have controllers render different views based on content type -- json, xml, html, js, etc are fundamentally different content types and require different content to be returned. This is the essence of the Model-View-Controller architecture that Rails is based on.

Comment: Is there a way to make `:mobile` views to fallback default views when not found? That wold make the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.

```
class ApplicationController
    ...
    def formats=(values)
        values << :html if values == [:mobile]
        super(values)
    end
    ...
end
```

It turns out Rails (3.2.11) already adds an :html fallback for requests with the :js format. Here's `ActionView::LookupContext#formats=`

```
# Override formats= to expand ["*/*"] values and automatically
# add :html as fallback to :js.
def formats=(values)
  if values
    values.concat(default_formats) if values.delete "*/*"
    values << :html if values == [:js]
  end
  super(values)
end
```

So you can override `#formats=` yourself and it will be conceivably no more gross and hacky than the existing Rails implementation.