# Render default template on MissingTemplate Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, missing-template

How can I catch the ActionView::MissingTemplate errors in Rails?

For example, my `PeopleController` has an Index method, but it doesn't need a template. When someone browses to root_url/people they get the default static error template.

And that's not the only controller with the issue; I want all missing template errors to redirect the user to my custom view.

1. How to catch the exception?
2. How to render a view afterwards?

Rails version - 3.0.19

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [render default template when requested template is missing in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851851/render-default-template-when-requested-template-is-missing-in-rails)

Which says:

> Use 'rescue_from' in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
    # use exception.path to extract the path information
    # This does not work for partials
  end
end
```

Comment: cool I'll try that! Yes I read that thread before posting; the first solution is for a different version of Rails; the second is a single controller solution; and the third one i don't really like... Thanks; and looks like I didn't notice the rescue_from solution from the other thread